# Ubuntu 18.04: osboxes.org virtual machine release upgrade is stuck

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I am in the middle of my release upgrade. I got the following message with a link, and the system is stuck. I am upgrading osboxes.org virtual machine on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release 
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore. 
For upgrade information, please visit: http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

==
I left the machine running, today when I started, I have following messages:

> Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                
> Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,340 kB]                                         
> Fetched 1,342 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                        
> authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg'  extracting
> 'focal.tar.gz'
> 
> Reading cache
> 
> Checking package manager Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree         Reading state information... Done Hit
> http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                  
> Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease      
> Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease    
> Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease     
> Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                             
> Reading package lists... Done     Building dependency tree          
> Reading state information... Done
> 
> Checking for installed snaps
> 
> Calculating snap size requirements
> 
> Updating repository information Get:1
> http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]          
> Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114
> kB]      Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports
> InRelease [101 k

and then lots of Gets
```

and then :

> Fetched 43.0 MB in 6s (3,491 kB/s)
>
> Checking package manager Reading package lists... Done     Building
> dependency tree           Reading state information... Done
>
> Calculating the changes
>
> Calculating the changes
>
> Do you want to start the upgrade?
>
> 2 packages are going to be removed. 110 new packages are going to be
> installed. 1254 packages are going to be upgraded.
>
> You have to download a total of 1,212 M. This download will take
> about 5 minutes with your connection.
>
> Installing the upgrade can take several hours. Once the download has
> finished, the process cannot be canceled.
>
> Continue [yN]  Details [d]Y
>
> Lock screen disabled
>
> Your lock screen has been disabled and will remain disabled until you
> reboot.
>
> To continue please press [ENTER] Inhibiting until Ctrl+C is pressed...

I have pressed the ENTER key, its still running.

Comment: What release are you using?   The error message you are posting implies you're not running 18.04, but another release.  Please enter `lsb_release -a` and post the details to your question (are you using 18.10/cosmic? or something else and not 18.04)

Comment: If you are running a 32-bit version of Ubuntu Server 18.04, then there are no further upgrades. If you're not sure whether your servers are running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you can check with `uname -i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Hi @Matigo, I got the message for GRUB: Configuring GRUB [right now cursor] /dev/sd (536870MB]; VBOX -HARDDISK) [option 2] -/dev/sda1(236870 MB; /) [option 3]-/dev/sda2 (1000MB; /boot); I think it is installing ubuntu 20, but it is a vitual machine of osboxes.org. It is running on ubuntu 18.04 64 bit system. Kindly guide me what option should I select for GRUB?

Comment: Hi Edmund, welcome. Actually did that but got stuck at the above link and then left my virtual machine running. It ran and now I need advise related to GRUB.

Comment: I did not install any GRUB option during configuration and pressed the space bar. It worked fine and I am able to install Ubuntu 20 on my virtual machine: sboxes@osboxes:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
osboxes@osboxes:~$